# java.lang.NullPointerException error in eclipse with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting this error while running my test in eclipse "An internal error occurred during: "Launching TestOne". `java.lang.NullPointerException`.Can someone please help me,I have added all the required jars.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TestOne {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Program Files/Drivers");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("google.com");
        System.out.println("Page is accessible");
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide us your code, otherwise we can't really help you

Comment: Hey @AT_SYdney, you're going to need to add a little bit more information to help us.  :)    I have always found Eclipse a complete dog to get working right, so hang in there.    If you could post the stack trace for this NullPointer so we can know what might be causing it.

Comment: Hey guys this is my code,sorry for not adding it earlier!                 
package AutomationTest;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TestOne {

 public static void main(String[] args) {  
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Program Files/Drivers");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  
  driver.get("https://google.com");  
  System.out.println("Page is accessible"); 
 }
}

Comment: Hi @AT_SYdney, edit your original question and post the code there in the corrrect format along with the stack trace.

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Program Files/Drivers");`
You need to set the path till the executable file

Comment: added.Still doesnt seem to work :(